# Internet Explorer Mobile 7 - Specifications

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I can not find detailed information about what is supported like CSS and JS in the new mobile IE. Is it like IE9 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At launch, it's basically IE7. If they don't upgrade it to IE9 specs pretty quickly, it'll kill the platform. Virtually all the sites written with mobile access in mind have been designed to use modern features in Webkit browsers, so throwing IE7 into the mix is just going to fail.

One of the best sites for info and news about the mobile browser world is [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/). The "Browsers" page (http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/browsers.html) has a write-up of the old Windows Mobile browser (based on IE6) and a brief paragraph about the new one, which he says is IE7 at launch but he expects them move to IE9.

The Quirksmode site also has a blog which is very good at keeping an ear to the ground with regard to developments in the mobile browser world. Worth having in your bookmarks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're asking about Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7, it is a mobile version of Internet Explorer 7 with some features "backported" from Internet Explorer 8.  It uses IE 7's rendering engine because it is optimized for environments with low memory.

Simply put, HTML and CSS will render the same as IE 7.

Comment: For reference, the feature "backported" from IE8 is the JavaScript engine

Comment: @Matt: thanks, I was looking for a reference to add but I got sidetracked (and I still can't find one).

Comment: see the comments on the blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/03/25/ladies-and-gentlemen-please-welcome-the-ie-mobile-user-agent-string.aspx